Applications moving between desktops when disconnecting external monitor
I have set up 7 desktops, when I'm not connected to an external monitor they all appear on my laptop display, when I am connected to an external monitor Desktop 1 is active on my laptop display and Desktops 2-7 are available on my external display.
I have the following scenario: I am connected to an external display and I have:
Application A opened on Desktop 1 (my laptop screen)
Application B opened on Desktop 2
Application C opened on Desktop 3
What I would expect:
Upon disconnecting the external monitor nothing changes and the applications stay in their respective desktops.
What actually happens
Applications A and B are now on Desktop 1 (split on my laptop screen) and Application C is on Desktop 2.
Is there an application or setting that can enable my desired behavior?
I'm using an M2 Macbook Air running macOS Sonoma 14.0

"When you are connected to an external monitor"...are you referring to your laptop or your desktop(s).  What Mac and what version of macOS are you running?

I'm not sure I understand your question. I updated the post to include the model and OS version.

@Allan Assume this is about Spaces (which Apple unfortunately calls Desktop #n in Mission Control).

Do things work better if you leave Desktop 2 empty and open B on #3, C on #4?

If I do what @nohillside is proposing, I end up having A on #1, B on #2 and C on #3, in a sense it's "better", but I would still prefer if applications stayed on the same desktop, since I want to build an association between an application and a specific desktop

Isn't "A on #1, B on #2 and C on #3" exactly what you ask for in the question?

What I ask for is that applications do not change workspaces when I connect / disconnect an external monitor. With the proposed solution they still do, but instead of desktops 1,2 and 3 being originally occupied, it's desktops 1, 3 and 4
